# Flickering issue with Form Navigation between forms in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am beginner to WPF, Can any one help me in navigating between forms without flickering. I am trying basic navigation between window forms. I have tried transition and user control navigation. It seems to be tedious for the basic navigation i am trying to do.

The application have lots of images in each forms, I think flickering occurs because of images being redrawn every time when each window loads. Is there anything different in WPF from the basic windows forms app in order to overcome the flickering issue. All I am asking is how to optimize or completely prevent flickering during form navigation in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You talk about Windows Forms and then immediately refer to WPF. From the problem you have described, it seems like you are trying to animate objects in a Windows Form, which is not a good idea, due to how Windows Forms are drawn.

For future reference, WPF has Windows and Windows Forms has Forms.

If you were to make the same project in WPF, it would be a simple to animate, and it would look good as well (No flickering due to GPU Acceleration).

I suggest that you take a look at WPF, and attempt to redesign the application in WPF if you want to be able to animate controls easily (You can't just copy paste the controls and code straight from Windows Forms).